# Is there any way to speed up my boats refueling without spending pearls?

Tags: seabeard

I've gotten to a point in Seabeard where I need to do a bunch of taxiing between islands. Unfortunately, I'm bouncing between them so quickly that my poor boat runs out of fuel, and the only way I can travel is to wait around, or spend 8 pearls refueling. Is there any other way to speed up this timer, or otherwise encounter it less frequently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seabeard was updated recently and that update provides the means to visit the islands without spending any energy.

Prior to the update, playing the mini-game to travel between the islands or using the airship to skip directly to the island both cost one lightning bolt of energy.

After the update, playing the mini-game still costs a single lightning bolt of energy, but using the airship to skip does not cost anything.

You will still want to use up your energy playing the mini-games so that you have a chance at the rewards provided at the end of them, but if you are out of energy, you can still access all the islands via the airship.